# Computer shuts down 10sec after turn on

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

I have a VAIO VPC-EA2GFX/B, and the OS is upgraded to Windows 10.

The fan is commonly running at full speed. I tried all trouble shooting I found on net, but could not solve the issue. Finally, I decided to replace the fan with a new fan. I installed the new fan (and applied a high quality coolmaster thermal paste). When I turn it on, first it increase the fan speed to max (I guess this is BIOS check on CPU fan), then immediately turns off (lets say, it turns off in max 10sec from pressing the power button).

I installed the old fan, it works, but the noise is still annoying.

Does anyone know what could be the problem ?

Comment: It certainly sounds like you are overheating.

Comment: But the computer is not even working, I even let it down for few hours to make sure. However, the very same procedure works perfectly fine with old fan ! but not with the brand new fan !

Comment: What reason do you have to believe it is NOT overheating? What you are describing is a classic example.

Comment: please read my description.

Comment: Is the new fan the EXACT model of the old fan? If you got a different fan, it could be a compatibility issue.

Comment: both are exactly same ! just out of curiosity; would be possible that the new fan _mistakenly_ is reverse spinning ?